# Copy/move files by folder name pattern in R

Tags: r, copy

I have a folder (`~/PATH/MYFOLDER`) with a lot of subfolders and files.
Subfolders are named, for example, as: LClass_orgx, LClass_orgy, LClass_phyw, LClass_detz, LClass_appq

Inside each subfolder has a lot of image files (*.png and/or *.jpg)

In `~/PATH/` I have folders with part of the name of subfolders, as: orgx, orgy, phyw, detz, appq

I would to copy image files of subfolders: LClass_orgx, LClass_orgy, LClass_phyw, LClass_detz, LClass_appq, to respective folders: orgx, orgy, phyw, detz, appq

Any help would be great.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to remove `"MYFOLDER/Lclass_"` from the file names. Something like this:

```
from = list.files(
  path = "~/PATH/MYFOLDER",
  pattern = "(png|jpg)$",
  recursive = TRUE, 
  full.names = TRUE
)

to = sub(x = from, pattern = "MYFOLDER/Lclass_", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)

file.copy(from = from, to = to)
```

This should take input from `list.files` like `"~/PATH/MYFOLDER/LClass_orgx/file.jpg"` (from) and change it to `"~/PATH/orgx/file.jpg"` (to), and then copy it accordingly. You could then use `file.remove` to delete the old ones. (Potentially you could do this all at once with `file.rename`, but it seems safer to copy and take a minute to check that things look right before deleting the old ones.)

If you need to be more specific in the sources, you could modify the `list.files(pattern)` to specify the source directories you mention, LClass_orgx, LClass_orgy, LClass_phyw, LClass_detz, LClass_appq.